# Problem with Spring MVC project on Eclipse: Error 404 when running on Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat, thymeleaf

I created a Spring MVC project in Eclipse using Thymeleaf as a template engine. After I set up the project and run it on the Tomcat server, I get a 404 error when I try to open the application in the browser.

I have verified that the Tomcat server configuration is correct and that all dependencies in my project are configured correctly. However, despite this, I continue to receive a 404 error.

I checked the Tomcat logs and didn't find anything suspicious there. I also made sure that the controllers and views were in the correct packages and that the @Controller and @RequestMapping annotations were configured correctly.

link to the repository with the project - https://github.com/nufbuf/TestSpringMVCproject/tree/master

[image]

Comment: You forgot to show us the actual 404 error, request and all.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a valid URL, unless you're deploying your app to `/hello_world` and there's a welcome page ready to be served. Your application as a whole has an application context path that should be part of your request. The servlet mapping within your application is not enough on its own, so it would have to look more like `http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-app1/hello_world`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mention specific application context then war file name will be the default context name

So, URL should be like below

http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-app1/hello-world

[image: Output]